# Creating a java program that iterates over every character in a file and places each character in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, file-io, char

To specify, the file starts with the row and column separated by a space, along with a maze one line after. For example:

mazeA.txt:

```
7 9
# # #####
# # #   #
# # # ###
# #     #
# ##### #
#       #
#########
```

What I need is for this to be put in a 2d array that looks like this:

```
[#,  , #,  , #, #, #, #, #]
[#,  , #,  , #,  ,  ,  , #]
[#,  , #,  , #,  , #, #, #]
[#,  , #,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , #]
[#,  , #, #, #, #, #,  , #]
[#,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , #]
[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
```

Heres the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int row, col;
        char[][] arr;
        
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the filename of the maze: ");
        String mzeFile = inp.next();                            //input stuff
        File fileObj = new File(mzeFile);
        
        System.out.println("File " +mzeFile+ " has been entered. Solving:\n");
        
        try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileObj))){
            //separate num 1 and 2 to get rows and columns
            String[] rc = read.readLine().split("\\s");
            row = Integer.parseInt(rc[0]);
            col = Integer.parseInt(rc[1]);
            arr = new char[row][col];
            
            System.out.println(row + " " + col);
            
            //start of iteration
            //attempts to start at second line and append maze characters
            //but i use readLine() twice so it just skips the first line of the maze
            while(read.readLine() != null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < row-1; i++) {
                    String line = read.readLine();
                    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                        arr[i][j] = (char) line.charAt(j);
                    }
                }
            //uncomment this to print array
                for(int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[x]));
                }
            
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("incorrect input");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What happens is the output comes out like this, where it prints out a line early and the 7th element is left empty.

```
EX:
[#,  , #,  , #,  ,  ,  , #]
[#,  , #,  , #,  , #, #, #]
[#,  , #,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , #]
[#,  , #, #, #, #, #,  , #]
[#,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , #]
[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
[
```

I can understand what the issue is, but I can't figure out how to circumvent it. Specifically, I need a way to simply align the 'j' loop with the proper line, and to do that I need to use readLine() in a better way. Yes, I know its far more simple than I'm making it.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling read.readLine() twice, once in the while and after in the body of for iteration.

Also i < row-1; is not correct, should be i < row;

Maybe this will give you idea:

```
String line = read.readLine();
for (int i = 0; i < row && line!=null; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = (char) line.charAt(j);
   }
line = read.readLine();
}
```

Comment: you are a SAVIOR

Answer (score 2):

You don't realy need those nested for loops. Just move the variable `line` outside the while loop, call `readLine` inside the condition  and add a line number counter `i`:

```
//rest of your code
try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileObj))) {
    //separate num 1 and 2 to get rows and columns
    String[] rc = read.readLine().split("\\s");
    row = Integer.parseInt(rc[0]);
    col = Integer.parseInt(rc[1]);
    arr = new char[row][col];

    System.out.println(row + " " + col);

    String line;
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
        arr[i] = line.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
        i++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("incorrect input");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably the following. NB, you don't need the first line in your maze file:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileToArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Path.of(args[0]))) {
                String[][] maze = stream.map(s -> s.split(" ")).toArray(String[][]::new);
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(maze));
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```